# Best way to join a free software project

Tags: gnu, sourceforge

I'm thinking about joining a free software project in order to increase my knowledge of how this kind of projects works, colaborating with people that I dont know (so far), and my C/C++ skills.

I`ve searched on sourceforge and so on, looking for projects that need developers... so my question is: how to join a existing project? (and find one I like)

Answer (score 2):

Pick one you like/are interested in, look over its bug tracker, and contribute patches.  As you demonstrate your ability to work along with the developers, you will generally be offered greater involvement (e.g. direct commit access).

Answer (score 0):

@geekosaur has some good points. (+1)

If those don't work, I would consider looking for the lead developer of a project (preferably one with decent activity and leadership) and asking what areas they would like assistance in.

I promise you, almost every open source project manager would absolutely welcome a fresh face to the team!